# How to efficiently serialize primitive arrays with Message Pack?

Tags: java, serialization, messagepack

Message Pack formats can serialize small integers or short strings in a compact way that merges type identifier with actual data.

Now when the data to serialize contains a primitive array (Java double[] for instance) then the Message Pack serialization will apparently waste one byte for each value in the array, to specify its type, instead of seeing that the type is constant for all values in the array.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior while remaining inter-operable? (other than using a binary string and converting in the application)